# Proof about difference of function values

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

Please provide me a proof for the following statement:

Suppose:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$$

$$x_0, h \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

$$x_1 = x_0+h_1e_1\quad x_2 = x_1 + h_2e_2\quad x_k = x_{k-1} + h_ke_k\quad x_n = x_0 + h$$

With $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the vectors of the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $h_i \in \mathbb{R}$ the i-th entry of $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then:

$$f(x + h) - f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})$$

Is this true aswell for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem.

The sum is telescoping,
so it is
$f(x_n)-f(x_0)$
no matter what
$f$ and the
$x_k$ are.

This gives you what you want.

Comment: What I don't understand is, how we know that this series really telescopes, I mean if $f$ would be a linear function I could believe it a bit more, but why does this work for any crazy function?

Comment: Just syntactically. For example, for $n=2$ this is $(f(x_2)-f(x_1))+(f(x_1)-f(x_0)) = f(x_2)-f(x_0)$.

Comment: Since this is meant for a proof about partial derivatives I thought far too complicated, I'm sry..thank you for your help!